# Google Drive API php does not return a list of all the folders from Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I use the Google Drive API v3 REST php for your web application to manage folders in Google Drive. At first, everything worked fine, but now does not. The fact that a request for a list of files, first return all the folders (as needed), then began to return the folder only shared, and now does only one folder (and its contents), and the other folders in the root directory of Google Drive if he did not exist for this request. The error may be what? How to fix it?

```
public function getFileList() {
    try {
        $this->client->setAccessToken($this->token);
        $files_list = $this->driveService->files->listFiles(array('fields' => "files(id, name, mimeType, parents, properties, trashed)"))->getFiles();
        return $files_list;
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
        PolytellHelper::_log('headman_id = '.$this->head . '| GoogleException: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your tried code and let people finding your issues

Comment: `public function getFileList() {
try {   
$this->client->setAccessToken($this->token);
$files_list = $this->driveService->files->listFiles(array('fields' => "files(id, name, mimeType, parents, properties, trashed)"))->getFiles();
return $files_list;
} catch ( Google_Exception $e ) {
PolytellHelper::_log('headman_id = ' . $this->head . '| GoogleException: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
}`